# Css: display a larger image (better quality) on hover from a seperate file

Tags: css, image, resize, hover

So im toying with the idea of displaying a larger (better quality image) when a user hovers over my thumbnails.
Not the fullsize version it links to upon click but still a size that shows a bit more detail providing it doesnt increase my page load time for my galleries a heap.

Even better would be if its possible to only have the images load on mouseover and not preloading when the page loads as that would hinder my speed efforts.

Would this be difficult to do?

Comment: Honestly, I would look for other methods for your performance improvements. I feel that what you want would not only be tricky, but detrimental for usability. But it all depends on what it is you're displaying and how. Have you researched ways of optimizing images for web?

Comment: my images are usually just thumbnails that link to the big version so no speed loss issues there. In what ways do you think usability would be affected? the images on hover would olny be about 20 or so kb.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with CSS, using `background: transparant url('') no-repeat;` at a hover action: http://jsfiddle.net/stidged/DqCcP/. 
I'm not familiar enough with JS plugins to suggest any of those, but i'm sure they're out there!

My point was that, when you request a non-preloaded image you have a short instance where the low-res image is gone and the better one gets requested and loaded, making it blink once when it isn't cached yet. Sprites remedy that glitchy impression for icons with hover states. Admittedly not the end of the world, but it's less than ideal.

Oh, and in case you're interested in performance, you might want to check out Chrome's PageSpeed extension to see how your site is doing. It does image optimisation analysis too and if there is room for improvement, you can get the optimised images directly from the plugin. Also, reading up on image-formats and the best Photoshop quality settings could help you save some of those precious kilobytes without lowering UX.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: im not sure how to do that